# pay with paypal, do I need ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, paypal, ssl-certificate

if I have a Pay with Paypal button on one of the pages of my website that sends the users to Paypal to process with payments, is it necessary to get an SSL certificate for my website? In other words, should the page on which the pay with Paypal button is be served over https?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Nope, if all of your sensitive information is going through paypal only.

if you save any sensitive information in your site (email / username / passwords) - then of course you must have certificate, because someone may steal the information.

but if paypal is doing all the work. you're good.

https://www.jvfconsulting.com/blog/is-an-ssl-cert-needed-for-paypal-transactions/

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, Pay with PayPal goes to their site and saves no sensitive information on yours, so a cert should be unnecessary.  However, if you're going to save any sensitive information yourself, you would be well served to do so over https.

Comment: Are email addresses, names, phone numbers considered as sensitive information?

Comment: Yes of course. If you have them please protect them

Answer (score 0):

Http sites are sent unencrypted and so can be interfered with and changed.

So it depends: Do you mind a hacker intercepting your plaintext http page and replacing that "Pay with PayPal" link to a different link that goes to paypa1.com or some such phishing site and they get the money instead of you?

If that's not something you want then go with https on your site as well.

Comment: you're correct, but the user will see that paypa1.com has probably non-valid certificate, the browser should usually warn the user before continuing

Comment: Do you really want to depend on that? They could also redirect to http://paypa1.com (so not require a cert) or use a domain that they have a cert for that looks official (e.g. https://mysecurepayment.com).

Comment: Of course not, but - they can use a domain that "looks" ok - but the certificate will not be CA approved. meaning, the browser should still warn the user.
Certificates are signed for exact name of a domain. meaning - gmail have a certificate signed by an approved CA (GeoTrust) for mail.google.com. the attacker can't get a CA certificate for his site mysecurepayment.com - as no one will approve it.

Comment: You can choose any domain that's free and get a cert for it. Just checked and mysecurepayment.com is not available but ppsecurepayment.com is for example. Easy to register that domain and get a cert for that and looks all green. Hopefully CA will revoke if someone complains it's a phishing site but point is you CAN get a CA approved cert for a site that might look OK to the average user. So, in short, if your site needs payment details (or any personal information) then you should use https - even if you offload the actual collection of said details to a third party like PayPal.

Comment: again, it's not that easy to get CA certificate for a fraud site. if you do it - you're already dead, as you can provide some kind of fake product anyway and users will not be aware of that.
i agree that https is needed. Check ebay - they are HTTP until you press "buy it now". so - i can fake that easily, and redirect to my site. no?

Comment: Of course it's easy to get a CA cert for a fake site! Keeping its a different matter. And yes EBay and Amazon are doing it wrong (and are regularly called out for it).

Comment: Allright, anyway, i see your point - it's valuable, but i still don't think it's that crucial if the site owner is willing to take the risk.